# Is there a way to target webkit browsers that are not the full mobile safari browser?

Tags: safari, webkit, mobile-safari, browser-detection

I have an app that is using a webkit browser and I would like to have some css only for this browser and not affect the full iOS safari browser. Does that make sense? Can it be done?

Comment: 'iOS' is the operating system on iPads en iPhones. If you want to exclude Safari on Apple desk- and laptops ('Mac OX' or 'Mac OS' or something similar), I would need you to rephrase your question. But that can be done, even though no distinction can be made between Chrome and Safari on iOS.